# Passing value from parent to child using slot probably

Tags: vue.js

I probably don't understand how it should be done. I spent a few hours to achieve this functionality but with no luck. Here is what I have:

Child

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Data from dialog: {{aaa}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'frm',
  props: [
    'aaa'
  ]
}
</script>
```

Parent:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :aaa="some"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'dlg',
  data: () => ({
    some: 'data from dialog'
  })
}
</script>
```

View:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <dlg>
      <frm></frm>
    </dlg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Dialog from '@/components/dialog.vue'
import Frm from '@/components/frm.vue'

export default {
  name: "View",
  components: {
    'dlg': Dialog,
    'frm': Frm
  }
};
</script>
```

**Edit: Real code**

dialog-template:

```html
    <template>
      <v-dialog
        v-model="internal.dialogOpened"
      >
        <!-- ... -->
        <slot :aaa="'dsada'"></slot>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
```

details-task-dialog:

```html
<template>
  <dlg-template large position='right' :onclose="close" :load="loadRetry">
    <task-details-form /> <!-- just regular component in which I want to get value passed through slot in dialog-template -->
  </dlg-template>
</template>
<script>
import DlgTemplate from '@/components/site/dialogs/dialog-template.vue'
export default {
// ...
  components: {
    'dlg-template': DlgTemplate,
    'task-details-form': DetailsForm,
  },
```

I want to avoid passing prop in View but I don't know how :/ I've read about 'slot-scope' unfortunately with no success. How to achieve such functionality?

Comment: What do you want to achieve please?

Comment: @KelvinOmereshone in real world app I need to pass reference of parent to child to be able to run methods in parent from child perspective. Maybe I'm using wrong approach - I don't know

Comment: If I understand you properly you need the parent to do something with a value in the child. Right? If that's the case then you can emit an event from the child component with the value then you use it in the parent component.

Comment: @KelvinOmereshone you might be right, I've seen somewhere such approach. Just to be 100% sure how i understand it: I'm emitting event from child and receive it on parent. I'm not using any bus or something, right?

Comment: Yes, you are not using an event bus. You can emit events and also pass in data while emitting that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: real code

Based on your real world code, you were only missing the attachment of the scope, see below.

dialog-template:

```html
    <template>
      <v-dialog v-model="internal.dialogOpened">
        <!-- ... -->
        <slot :aaa="'dsada'"></slot>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
```

details-task-dialog:

```html
<template>
  <dlg-template large position='right' :onclose="close" :load="loadRetry">
    <task-details-form v-slot="{ aaa }"> 
      <!-- you can use the var `aaa` here  -->
    </task-details-form>
  </dlg-template>
</template>
```

I'd still wager if you want to use `aaa` inside `task-details-form` component you have to pass it down as a prop. But it looks wierd to me, because I'm unsure of the execution order right now (v-slot vs v-bind), but try it like this:

```html
<template>
  <dlg-template large position='right' :onclose="close" :load="loadRetry">
    <task-details-form v-slot="{ aaa }" :your-a-prop-name="aaa" />
  </dlg-template>
</template>
```

### Edit 2: after testing

v-bind shorthand is not working on `<slot>`:

dialog-template:

```html
    <template>
      <v-dialog v-model="internal.dialogOpened">
        <!-- ... -->
        <slot v-bind:aaa="'dsada'"></slot>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
```

details-task-dialog:

```html
<template>
  <dlg-template large position='right' :onclose="close" :load="loadRetry">
    <template v-slot="{ aaa }"> <!-- has to preceed v-bind -->
    <task-details-form :propertyOnComponent="aaa" /> <!-- now you cand bind it --> 
    </template>
  </dlg-template>
</template>
```

#### Original:

I think you misunderstood slots. Check the docs:

That slot has access to the same instance properties (i.e. the same “scope”) as the rest of the template. The slot does not have access to child’s scope.

[Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

So you could do that, but then your code becomes:

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <dlg>
      <frm>
        <child :aaa=“dialogData” />
      </frm>
    </dlg>
  </div>
</template>
```

Frm:

```
<template>
  <div>
    From component
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you would define a slot on frm as you are suggesting, you would be able to fill that slot with a specific template and you can receive(!) the scope for that slot.

The deprecated slot-scope which you mentioned would provide you with a bound context from the child to be exposed in your overriding slot in the parent, that’s the opposite of what you want.

Just out of curiosity, why not send down the dialog data to the form as a property? That’s exactly what it’s for.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to :aaa prop in View. The value of :aaa exists only in dlg component. That's why I'd like to avoid this solution

Comment: Is it a special dialog or your own component?

Comment: Mix of mine and vuetify

Comment: Without any code, I don't really understand how the `aaa` value only exists in the child component. If I remember correctly, you define the content of a vuetify dialog from the parent component via its default slot, so the value should be available, but as I said without your template code we can't really say... 

I think you should go with the approach from @kelvin-omereshone and emit the value from your custom dialog component.

Comment: The parent of slot is v-dialog: <v-dialog><slot :aaa="something"></slot></v-dialog>

Comment: Is that supposed to be your customization of the dialog? Just show us this component and its parent with everything you can post publicly.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( How does it know which prop in slot should be used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215810/discussion-between-janos-veres-and-artur-siwiak).